# Expansion of Beta function near negative integers

Tags: taylor-expansion, laurent-series, beta-function

Is there a closed form expression for the coefficients (after Taylor expansion) of the Beta function $B(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$ around an arbitrary negative integer let's say $x=-k$ and $y=-l$? I want an expression of the coefficients of the expansion in terms of $k$ and $l$.

Is there an analogous expression for $\partial_x\partial_y B(x,y)$ around an arbitrary negative integer  $x=-k$ and $y=-l$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I know the leading singularity (expansion using the Gamma function), But I need higher-order terms as well.  I have the expression for special value but I want a general closed-form expression.